# How to configure lid close action as hibernate in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, hibernate, lid

I want to configure my laptop (ASUS UX461UN) to go to hibernate when I close the lid. I tried 3 basic suggestions that I saw as a result of my research.

1. Run command `sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and configure **#HandleLidSwitch=suspend** line for hibernate,
2. Increase swap space,
3. Disable secure boot.

None of these worked. Hibernate is an important feature for me, especially for keeping ongoing tasks. How do I get my laptop to go into hibernate mode when I close the lid? Is including this a big problem for Ubuntu? Since hibernate is totally removed after some versions.

Comment: did you leave the # in front of HandleLidSwitch as listed above?

Comment: I removed #, that's what I mean by configure.

Comment: And of course replaced "suspend" with "hibernate".

Comment: Did you restart the systemd login service.
`sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`